# how to solve this inequiality $xyz ⩾ (x+y-z)(y+z-x)(z+x-y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Assuming positive real values of $x,y,z$, how can we prove that $(xyz) ⩾ (x+y-z)(y+z-x)(z+x-y)$

Comment: That should be a $\geqslant$ instead of >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $(a+b-c)(b+c-a) \le b^2$, by AM-GM. Use this pairwise for $3$ pairs. You can assume $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle for if not the inequality is trivially true.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for hint.

Comment: It’s really an awesome hint. What I want to know is how you got it? I mean in Algebra how do we come up with those things?